# Программа считает количество повторений чисел в строке, но последнее значение не учитывает. Как исправить?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int a = 0, v = 0;
if (cin >> a) 
{
    int cnt = 1;
    while (cin >> v)
    {
        if (v == a)
            ++cnt;
        else
        {
            cout << a << " o " << cnt << " t ";
            a = v;
            cnt = 1;
        }
    }
    cout << a << " o " << cnt << " t ";

}

return 0;
```

}

Comment: А поточнее описать, что она **должна** делать? *"Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение"*

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, все у вас работает (если я верно *догадываюсь*, что вы хотите - вы же так и не снизошли к описанию, что программа должна делать). Разве что лепит все одной макарониной в одну строку...

Вы по окончании ввода закрываете `cin`? Ctrl-Z в Windows, Ctrl-D, кажется, в Linux?

Если нет - то кто же вам виноват... Ну, введите как окончание ввода **не** число...

Comment: про endl я знаю, меня не это смущает. Если программа получает на ввод 42 42 42 55 55 666 100 100 100, то она выведет 42 o 3 t, 55 o 2 t, 666 o 1. А вот 100 o 3 t не выводит, а должна. По-идее не работает cout, который принадлежит первому условию. Ну в целом если ввести не число в конце, оно конечно работает, но что-то какой-то метод кустарный.

Comment: Еще раз. У вас указано, что окончанием ввода становится невозможность прочесть очередное число. `while(cin>>v)`. Грубо говоря, это происходит, когда `cin` перестает нормально работать - поток закрыт, поток получил неверные данные... Не нравится так - меняйте логику. **КАК** вы определяете (хотите определять), что ввод завершен? Что все, пора заканчивать программу, выходя из цикла `while`?